# missing Types for postgis after created new schema in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgis-installation

I have a Postgres database called `db_1` and a schema `s1`

(Using PgAdmin)

1. Then I installed `postgis` and `postgis_topology`.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis_topology;
```

under `s1`, I can see 18 Types including the `geography`, `geometry` ...etc

2. Then I update the parameter `search_path` from `s1, s2, public`
3. Then I created another schema `s2`, but this time `s2` has no `type`
4. Run my flyway sql on Spring,

`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "geography" does not exist`

Comment: Which postgis version are you using?

Comment: btw: do you really need to have the extension in a different schema? PostGIS isn't supposed to be relocalable: `As of PostGIS 2.3, the postgis extension was changed to no longer allow relocation. All function calls within the extension are now schema qualified.` Although there are a few tricks to make it work, there will always be a few functions that simply won't work , as they have the schema "hard coded" in the schema of installation

Comment: @JimJones, I am using postgres 11.x with postgis 2.5, 

My use case is : I have two microservices, one connects to `s1` and the other connects to `s2` schema. Both microservices need to use `geography` type.

i am not sure if I `need to have the extension in a different schema`. Can you advise how to achieve the use case? Thanks

Comment: That's really odd. Having the search_path properly updated should do the trick: `ALTER DATABASE db SET search_path = public,s1,s2;` I tested it here creating `s1` and `s2` and only after that updating the search_path.. and it worked. Can you add to your question exactly how you did all these steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is not about `how to install`, but how to `connect`

I am using Spring to connect to the pgsql, for example, I am connecting to schema `s1` and the extension is installed on `postgis`.

When I set the connection string to the following, then it works:

`?currentSchema=s1,postgis`